# How to show dynamic API data on table view cell if the response type is not always same

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a API request, that has questions and related responses .
If question is for eg 1. , then response is button
if question is 2., then response is Switch
If question is 3., the. rewponse is Image.
Depending on the response, I have to add either a button,Switch or Image.

The API data is dynamic.

I dont know how to proceed !
What I tried is,
I added a Table View Cell,
then as per the response, I am adding a subview to that cell !
The problem is, the Questions are many.
My subview is getting reused once I scroll the view!

```
cell. textLable = Question[indexpath.row]
let responseType = Responses[indexPath.row]


if responseType == “button”{
cell.addSubview(buttonCell)
}

if responseType == “image”{
cell.addSubview(imageCell)
}

if responseType == “switch”{
cell.addSubview(swichCell)
}
```

When I scroll the tableView,
my subView gets added anyWhere as the cells are getting reused !

Comment: Please provide your `cellForRowAt` code

Comment: I think we need to give the perfect frame or constrain to fix view at particular are. Do you know about it?

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, ***"the cells are getting reused !"***

That means you are adding a new subView every time the cell is reused... you need to remove what you added previously:

```
// call a func in your cell to "reset" it... remove any previously added subviews, etc
cell.reset()

cell. textLable = Question[indexpath.row]
let responseType = Responses[indexPath.row]


if responseType == “button”{
cell.addSubview(buttonCell)
}

if responseType == “image”{
cell.addSubview(imageCell)
}

if responseType == “switch”{
cell.addSubview(swichCell)
}
```

You could also do this by implementing `prepareForReuse` and "resetting" your cell content there.

Answer (score 0):

if there are only 3 type of cells that you need to construct, than register 3 different type cells for Table View like

```
table.register(imageCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "imageCell")
table.register(buttonCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "buttonCell") 
table.register(switchCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "switchCell")
```

You need to subclass the UITableViewCell for this purpose

Now after register the cells, You can use it in cellforrow method like this

```
let responseType = Responses[indexPath.row]
var cellIdentifier = "buttonCell"
if (responseType == "image"){
   cellIdentifier = "imageCell"
}else if(responseType == "switch"){
   cellIdentifier = "switchCell"
}
let cell = dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
```